Analysis of GBS before and after COVID-19 while adjusting for confounding variables
I am new to statistics and would appreciate the help! I am using SPSS and am working on a project where I want to analyze the impact of COVID-19 on Group B Streptococcus (GBS). I therefore have 4 groups (GBS positive before and after COVID, and GBS negative before and after COVID). I have several variables, both continuous and categorical (ex: number of transfers before and after COVID, reasons for transfers, gestational age at delivery, APGAR scores, etc.). I also have demographic data for the groups (ex: age of mother, gravida, para, number of previous cesarian, etc.) that I believe could be confounding variables. I have performed the Mann-Whitney U and Chi-square test on those confounders, and also on the other variables, and found that some were significant (meaning that the demographics for before and after COVID for GBS positive/negative were statistically different). Is there a way to perform my analysis while adjusting for those factors?
Thank you!

Welcome to Cross Validated! Just to clarify, do you have one set of patients and you have their before and after COVID statuses or you have those 4 groups and you want to analyze what makes them different?
